# Add data-id attribute to link inside bootstrap popover element

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I have a friends list that when clicked on, will pop up with a bootstrap popover with an option to send that user a message.

[image]

In order to do that I need the popover to know which friend was clicked so it can store the id of that friend.

I tried using the parent elements of the popover to find the friend that the popover is attached to. But it seems the popover doesn't know anything about what is clicked in order for it to pop up. That is, it doesn't have context.

I tried storing the id of the friend in the popover in a data-id attribute. However, it only appears on the element that brings up the popover, and not the popover itself. Here's what I mean below:

My code:

[image]

How it appears on the page (chrome dev tools):

[image]

As you can see, the data-id attribute does appear as part of the data-content attribute of the popover. However, the actual popover will not include this data-id attribute, even though it includes the other attributes (href, class).

[image]

How do I get this information to the "message" link on the popover?

Answer (score 0):

Though I couldn't find a solution to this (maybe because bootstrap doesn't support adding 'data-id' attributes to the popover's 'data-content' attribute), I found a very simple work-around.

You can add a div with the id set to whatever you want, and it won't affect the display but will have the id attribute that you can use javascript to retrieve.

```html
<div class="user-info user-image chat_user loadChatroom friend-view" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="top" 
              data-content="<div class='hidden-friend-id' id='<%= friend.id %>'></div> <a href='/view-profile/<%= friend.id %>'>View profile</a><br/> <a href='' class='message-friend' data-id='<%= friend.id %>'>Message</a>">
```

Answer (score 0):

add satitize: false and you can add anything in the element